# Using after_save to update all belongs_to records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, after-save

I'm building a project management application in Ruby on Rails (3.0). I am trying to figure out how to update all the tasks of a project on update of a project column. Here is the situation.

I am listing all the projects, as expected, in /projects/index.html.erb. I'm using a sortable list ([from Ryan Bates tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists)) to update the project.position field as the user sorts the list.

When the project list gets sorted the `project.position` column gets updated on each sort, I also want to update the task.project_position column of all the tasks that `belong_to` that project. So task.project_position = project.position.

I am guessing that this is done through an after_save in the project model but I could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the value multiple times - that's `redundant` and `unnecessary` in all but a few esoteric cases.

In Ruby/Rails you can `delegate` from the task to the project for the position method like this (in your Task model):

```
delegate :position, :to => :project, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
```

With that in place, you now have `task.project_position` which will return the value of project.position via the association between the two, without duplication of that data element across all tasks in the project.

All this assumes that task `belongs_to :project` (and probably, project `has_many :tasks`).

[more detailed explanation.](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/)

If you feel you really must go the de-normalized route for some reason, then yes, after_save would be the place to do it.